# Mac App Testing

Tags: macos, testing, mac-app-store

Is there a website or service that I can use to test my mac app store apps? I've seen macdeveloper.net, but being that it costs money I want to make sure that there aren't any other services that are better. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoting your question, because I don't know any other service and would be interested to see what else exists and how good it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [macdeveloper.net](http://macdeveloper.net) about 2 years ago, for a Mac app (yes, there were Mac apps even before the Mac App Store).
It was a really great experience. Feedback from beta-testers was great, in quality and quantity. It helped me to spot and fix some very subtle bugs. This is great, because I didn't want real users to encounter them.

I find the price asked for the service (less than $20) very reasonable:

- Think about how much it will cost you if even one bug is not found until on the App Store, and a user posts a very negative review because of it.
- The infrastructure provided to ease your beta-testing phase is great. The time saved was enough to make me feel it was worth it. I prefer to spend my time coding and improving my marketing than to deal with problem someone else resolved better than me
- When I had questions, the support was replying very quickly, with great and appropriate answers
- ...

Comment: alright, looks like that's what I'll go with. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried Using :
https://github.com/CodeFacet/COMBAT + Accessibility Inspector(Developer Tools in XCode)

It's Still under development but a great tool to work with. :)

It's written down in Objective-C, so you can use its libraries inside XCode only along with a Unit Testing Project

So better Test Management and easy Test Case Writing.

PS: It works with Simulators as well so you can even Test IOS Apps